# Dynamically add columns for csv data JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add columns according to the data. Data is the education background of each person, and everyone might have different education length according to how many degrees they have.

My code:

```
email: careerData.email,
gender: careerData.gender,
education: careerData.education.map(education => education.institute),
```

This is giving me all of that data in one field, but I want it in different fields. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have data in the following form:

```
data = {
    email: careerData.email,
    gender: careerData.gender,
};

careerData.education.forEach((education, index) => data['education'+ index] = education.institute)
```